# Найти по атрибуту и тегу атрибута данные внутри этого тега

Tags: java, xml

```
if(textField.getText().equals(String.format("%s with %s", ((nodeList.item(i)).getNodeName()), (nodeList.item(i)).getAttributes().item(0) ))){
   System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getTextContent());
}
```

Comment: <product name="rrr">
        <id>p04</id>
        <name>Product 4</name>
        <price>400</price>
    </product>

Comment: ввожу product with rrr и мне не выдает ид имя и цену продукта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пришлось полностью восстанавливать пример, у вас не хватает **.getNodeValue()**

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

    StringBuilder xmlStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    xmlStringBuilder.append(
            "<product name=\"rrr\"> <id>p04</id> <name>Product 4</name> <price>400</price> </product>");
    ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(
            xmlStringBuilder.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
    Document doc = builder.parse(input);
    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("product");
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

        Node node = nodeList.item(i);
        String nodeName = node.getNodeName();
        String item = node.getAttributes().item(0).getNodeValue();
        if ("product with rrr".equals(String.format("%s with %s", nodeName, item))) {
            System.out.println(node.getTextContent());
        }
    }
```

Просьба предоставляйте больше данных и кода в вопросах